# Edit 'more details' link on WooCommerce single Product Page / Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to get my head around where the various template files are stored for WooCommerce, Wordpress, & the theme I am using (Reykjavic).

I have successfully created a child theme to make my amendments and have found and edited some template files successfully.

I'd like to move the link to be part of the text itself and not a separate paragraph. The templates are displaying it on the page like this:

[image]

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
 <p>The B&amp;G Zeus3 Glass Helm 19 is designed specifically for blue water sailing, multihulls and superyachts; this premium, super-fast, super large-screen, multifunction display sits at the heart of your fully integrated navigation system and comes with B&amp;G’s unique sailing features including SailSteer and RacePanel.</p>
<p class="product-description-link-container">
 <a href="#tab-description" class="product-description-link">More details…</a>
</p>
```

I have found this WooCommerce template file which I believe sends the short description to the page:

```
/**
 * Single product short description
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.3.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

global $post;

$short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

if ( ! $short_description ) {
    return;
}

?>
<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
    <?php echo $short_description; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
</div>

</div>
```

I believe I need to find or amend the post excerpt where this is happening. `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );` but unsure where this is being set?

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use your IDE to search for `woocommerce_short_description` across the code base, then you will see that there’s several filter functions added in `woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php`. You’ll have to go and figure out which one of those does what (`wpautop` might play into this), and then see if removing that particular filter from within your own theme/plugin works. If not, you might need to add your own filter function at the end of the whole process, to somehow fix the HTML code that was assembled up to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'modify_short_description' );

function modify_short_description( $short ) {
    return $short . '<a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.google.com" class="read_more">More details</a>';
}
```

Try this code snippet